# Trouble moving to Repository (only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to move a LINQ to entities query over to using a repository rather than DbContext directly.  I'm having an issue with one of the queries giving me the error:  `"only primitive types ('such as Int32, String, and Guid') are supported in this context)"`

This is what I'm trying:

```
var data = from SurveyResponseModel in surveyResponseRepository.Query
    group SurveyResponseModel by SurveyResponseModel.MemberId into resultCount
    select new ResultsViewModel()
    {
        MemberId = resultCount.Key,
        PatientFollowUpResult = surveyResponseRepository.Query.Count(r => r.PatientFollowUp),
        PatientFollowUpResultPct = (int)Math.Round(((decimal)surveyResponseRepository.Query.Count(r => r.PatientFollowUp) / (decimal)totalResponsesResult) * 100),

        ChangeCodingPracticeResult = surveyResponseRepository.Query.Count(r => r.ChangeCodingPractice),
        ChangeCodingPracticeResultPct = (int)Math.Round(((decimal)surveyResponseRepository.Query.Count(r => r.ChangeCodingPractice) / (decimal)totalResponsesResult) * 100),

        EnhanceDiagnosticAcumenResult = surveyResponseRepository.Query.Count(r => r.EnhanceDiagnosticAcumen),
        EnhanceDiagnosticAcumenResultPct = (int)Math.Round(((decimal)surveyResponseRepository.Query.Count(r => r.EnhanceDiagnosticAcumen) / (decimal)totalResponsesResult) * 100)
    }
```

This is my SurveyResponseModel:

```
public class SurveyResponseModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int ResponseId { get; set; }

        public int MemberId { get; set; }

        public int ProgramId { get; set; }

        // "If yes, what changes did you make? Mark all that apply."

        [DisplayName("Did you make any changes in your practice, research, or administration activities as a result of participating in this CME activity?")]
        public string CmeChanges { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Better patient follow-up")]
        public bool PatientFollowUp { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Change my coding practice")]
        public bool ChangeCodingPractice { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Enhance my diagnostic acumen")]
        public bool EnhanceDiagnosticAcumen { get; set; }
}
```

This is the ViewModel that displays the data:

```
public int MemberId { get; set; }

public int ProgramId { get; set; }

// "If yes, what changes did you make? Mark all that apply."

[DisplayName("Did you make any changes in your practice, research, or administration activities as a result of participating in this CME activity?")]
public string CmeChangesResult { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Better patient follow-up")]
public int PatientFollowUpResult { get; set; }

public int PatientFollowUpResultPct { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Change my coding practice")]
public int ChangeCodingPracticeResult { get; set; }

public int ChangeCodingPracticeResultPct { get; set; }

[DisplayName("Enhance my diagnostic acumen")]
public int EnhanceDiagnosticAcumenResult { get; set; }

public int EnhanceDiagnosticAcumenResultPct { get; set; }
```

Query Member inside the repository:

```
public IQueryable<SurveyResponseModel> Query
        {
            get
            {
                return dbSet.AsQueryable<SurveyResponseModel>();
            }
        }
```

Comment: aren't you doing a 6 * N + 1 select this way? isn't surveyResponseRepository.Query executed deferred?

Comment: Don't you want the property values in the view model *per group*, i.e. `resultCount` instead of `surveyResponseRepository.Query`? You are querying the whole table in each group element (will have always the same result for every group item).

Comment: If I switch surveyResponseRepository.Query.Count to a resultCount.Count it's only displaying data for the first data entry in the database.

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, but what is your code *supposed* to do? For me it looks like you are grouping survey responses for each member (a member can have multiple responses I guess) and you want to aggregate some values over the responses of a member. But `PatientFollowUpResult` in your view model for example would count for *all* members, not only for the member of that group. Even if you don't get an exception, it will still give you just the wrong result.

Comment: It is supposed to tally the results for all members total, And then gives the percentage that answered boolean "true" to the question.  The calculation works fine when I use dbContext directly rather than a repository interface, I'm just not sure why using a repository is throwing an exception.

Comment: Looks like the difference must be in `dbSet`. Can you show how dbSet is created?